Don't understand step in paper detailing De Moivre's derivation of the normal distribution
I am reading a paper detailing De Moivre's derivation of the normal distribution function, and the paper makes the following step:
(in the first line there should be a '+' between the first pair of brackets in the $\exp$ and the second pair of brackets). Manually I worked out that the first pair expands out to $$-\epsilon + \frac{\epsilon^2}{2np} - \frac{\epsilon^2}{np} + \frac{\epsilon^3}{2n^2p^2} - \frac{\epsilon}{2np} + \frac{\epsilon^2}{4n^2p^2}$$
And the second pair expands out to $$\epsilon + \frac{\epsilon^2}{2n(1-p)} - \frac{\epsilon^2}{n(1-p)} - \frac{\epsilon^3}{2n^2(1-p)^2} + \frac{\epsilon}{2n(1-p)} + \frac{\epsilon^2}{4n^2(1-p)^2}$$
So when adding, I get $$-\epsilon + \frac{\epsilon^2}{2np} - \frac{\epsilon^2}{np} + \frac{\epsilon^3}{2n^2p^2} - \frac{\epsilon}{2np} + \frac{\epsilon^2}{4n^2p^2} + \epsilon + \frac{\epsilon^2}{2n(1-p)} - \frac{\epsilon^2}{n(1-p)} - \frac{\epsilon^3}{2n^2(1-p)^2} + \frac{\epsilon}{2n(1-p)} + \frac{\epsilon^2}{4n^2(1-p)^2}$$
But it seems that they have eliminated a few terms of this expansion. I am not sure how they did this step, I am unable to add the terms together in a way that leaves the expansion that they have provided - am I incorrect in my expansion? Or did they 'approximate' away the last $3$ terms? If so, what is the criteria by which those $3$ terms specifically were chosen to be eliminated for approximation?

Why is an expansion necessary in this situation?

I can't see how they go from the first line to the second line, so I expanded to understand explicitly what is happening - but upon expanding my result doesn't align with theirs, hence my confusion.

What I was trying to get at is that an expansion isn't necessary. For example, you get an $\epsilon^3$ term, but this is not possible, as none of the exponents are applied to more than one term.
